# Spring Data JPA Repository Method Query Cannot Parse Property Name Following OrderBy

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My Repository Method Query cannot parse a property name that comes after the `OrderBy`, but it can if it follows the `findBy` or `findAllBy`. The attribute in my entity that is giving me issues is `zIndex`

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity
public class DisplayLayer 
{
  @Id
  @Column(name="DISPLAY_LAYER_ID")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="DISPLAY_CONTAINER_ID")
  private DisplayContainer displayContainer;

  @Column(name="NAME")
  private String name;

  @Column(name="Z_INDEX")
  private Long zIndex;

  @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
  private String description;

  // Getters & Setters
}
```

**Repository Class**

```
public interface DisplayLayerRepository extends BaseRepository<DisplayLayer, Long>
{
  // This one method query works just fine
  public List<DisplayLayer> findByZIndex(Long pZIndex);

  // These two throw the same error:
  // Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [ZIndex]
  //
  // public List<DisplayLayer> findAllByOrderByZIndexAsc();
  // public List<DisplayLayer> findByDisplayContainerIdOrderByZIndexAsc(Long pDisplayLayerId);
}
```

So in my first method query, when `OrderBy` is not used, it correctly parses it as `[zIndex]`, but when it follows the `OrderBy` for some reason it capitalizes the z: `[ZIndex]`.

Is this a known issue, or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**
What makes me think there might be a bug with the parser is that if I update `zIndex` to `IndexZ` in my entity and then change my query methods from `OrderByZIndex` to `OrderByIndexZ` everything works.

This solution is not ideal though as the database table is `Z_INDEX` and that has a specific meaning when talking about layering of graphics.

Comment: It has to do with some naming strategy hibernate uses. You may look at various naming strategy to select from to enforce column name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a bug but there is a simple workaround, please try :

```
displayLayerRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Order.desc("zIndex").ignoreCase()));
```

I suppose DisplayLayerRepository extends JpaRepository.

It's similar when you use parameters in your findBy method. Define in your repository empty method :

```
public List<DisplayLayer> findByDisplayContainerId(Long pDisplayLayerId, Sort sort);
```

Then you can call it by :

```
displayLayerRepository.findByDisplayContainerId(1L, Sort.by(Sort.Order.desc("zIndex").ignoreCase()));
```

Comment: I'll have to look into this more as I need to be able to restrict it as well i.e. instead of `findAll` `findByDisplayContainerId`.

More importantly, where is the correct place to report this bug? I don't mind using my workaround until it gets fixed.

Comment: i complete my answer, it is possible in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JpaSort in query. As in your case, it looks something like this:

```
Sort sort = JpaSort.unsafe(Sort.Direction.ASC, "zIndex");

List<DisplayLayer> zIndexes = displayLayerRepository.findByZIndex(pZIndex, sort);
```

and your query in Repository will look like this:

```
public List<DisplayLayer> findByZIndex(Long pZIndex, Sort sort);
```